# How Do You Define a Kubernetes Service TargetPort as a String?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus-operator, ocelot, thanos

Thanos requires a targetPort defined as a string in the Service for the ServiceMonitor to communicate with it.

However, just defining the targetPort as a string causes problems. I believe that something more is needed in the Deployment. I think the targetPort 'web' must be defined in the Deployment.

Can anyone assist with how the Deployment should look?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  labels:
    app: my-app
    tenant: a
    servicemonitor: my-servicemonitor
    monitor: "true"
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: web
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: web
  selector:
    app: my-app
---
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-app
    tenant: a
  name: my-monitor
spec:
  endpoints:
    - port: web
      path: /metrics
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
      - my-namespace
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      servicemonitor: my-servicemonitor
      monitor: "true"
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple example of defining the targetPort as string is to first define it in the Deployment before you can refer to it as a string in targetPort in a service. Below is the simple example to show how to map "http" ( port name) from deployment in a service targetPort spec.

**Deployment:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello
      tier: backend
      track: stable
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello
        tier: backend
        track: stable
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hello
          image: "gcr.io/google-samples/hello-go-gke:1.0"
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
```

**Service:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello
    tier: backend
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: http
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set targetPort to an integer value or a name.

If you refer to it by name, that name has to be defined within the pod(s) in `spec > containers[n] > ports[n] > name`

If you refer by integer, there is no need to define ports in pods at all, although it's reasonable to still do it for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

By providing a matching port name in the Deployment, things appear to work properly:

```
ports:
- name: web
  containerPort: 80
```